# Angularjs + Spring Boot REST (HATEOAS) - Passing angular variables into angular methods

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

The problem is the attribute **ng-click="deleteItem('{|{ reservation._links.self.href }|}')**

```
<body ng-app="ReservationList">
<div class="content" ng-controller="ReservationListController">
    <div class="panel" ng-repeat="reservation in reservations">
        <div class="itemId{|{reservation.id}|}">
            <button class="close" ng-click="deleteItem('{|{ reservation._links.self.href }|}')">X</button>
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{|{ reservation.firstName }|}</h3>
                <h3 class="panel-title">{|{ reservation.lastName }|}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Interestingly, when i inspect the html source, the ng-click will look like this:

```
ng-click="deleteItem('http://localhost:8080/reservation/1')"
```

However when launching the ng-click function it will just give the non-compiled attribute name as the parameter:

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/%7B%7C%7B%20reservation._links.self.href%20%7D%7C%7D 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

The DELETE request should have http://localhost:8080/reservation/1 as the endpoint but somehow it doesnt parse the attribute when i send the DELETE request and will just annoy me with this unparsed {[{ reservation._links.self.href }]}.

Should I even use HAL links as the endpoints for CRUD operations or is it more wise to just give the id to my delete function.

Just to note DELETE requests on http://localhost:8080/reservation/1 do work when i hardcode it in.

Comment: Is there anything like " {|{ }]}" in Angular because I never came across this

Comment: If I am not mistaken you would expect "{{ }}" but in angular you can change the syntax to whatever you want, so I changed it to "{[{}]}" :) For more info you can go to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Comment: Thanks bro i was not aware about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass `Angular Expression` to function. Pass the variables directly without `{{}}`.

In your case

```
ng-click="deleteItem(reservation._links.self.href)"
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed it right away :) will upvote as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

You could try simply not using the expression syntax and pass it directly:

`ng-click="deleteItem(reservation._links.self.href)"`

Perhaps I'm wrong, but I'm not actually familiar with this syntax:

`ng-click="{|{expression}|}"`

Shouldn't be like this instead (note the lack of the pipe `|`)?

`ng-click="{{expression}}"`

Also, I think you would want to include the deleteItem call within the expression scope, no?

So, you'd end up with this:

`ng-click="{{deleteItem(reservation._links.self.href)}}"`

This binds the clicking of that `HTML` element to the invocation of the model/controller in scope that has the `deleteItem` function, passing into it the desired href from the expression.

Read up on expressions here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: yes by default it is {{ }} but i changed it to {|{ }]} through the configuration as it was conflicting with some other tags. Passing it directly without the tags worked, thank you :), will upvote as soon as i can